# How to run and compile java program on hadoop 0.23.0 MR2

Tags: java, hadoop, javac

I created a .java file to run on cloudera hadoop. To compile it,

```
   javac -classpath $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client- core-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -d multifetch_classes MultiFetch.java
```

Errors:

```
MultiFetch.java:12: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
                         ^ 
MultiFetch.java:13: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
                         ^
MultiFetch.java:14: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                       ^
MultiFetch.java:15: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
```

Am i selecting wrong jar to execute the file or am i following wrong procedure to compile the java file. Please do let some correct this error.

Comment: It looks like you have a space in the path in your `-classpath` argument between `hadoop-mapreduce-client-` and `core-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the above errors are related with not able to find Hadoop libraries to compile your sample application.

A sample Java based Map/Reduce sample build command is as below:

```
$javac \
 -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar \
 -d wordcount_classes \
 WordCount.java
```

In my case, the jar file is `hadoop-0.20.203.1-SNAPSHOT-core.jar`. If you take a look at your command you will see there is something not right:

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client- core-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -d multifetch_classes MultiFetch.java
```

What you can do is you can build you sample just by using `classpath` as given in sample above.